# Is it possible to have timeline marker / add image to the slider in WPF using Blend?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend, timeline, marker

I have research on my question but it seem like only silverlight have timeline marker.. I want to show the user when is the next part of the video going to start at on the video slider but I really got no idea how to do it. Or is it possible to add images near the slider, to show user where/when will be the next video parts going to start?

I am totally new to WPF & Blend & C#...

Thanks.

Comment: Possible, indirect, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411568/mediaelement-markers-missing-in-wpf.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered in [MediaElement Markers Missing in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411568/mediaelement-markers-missing-in-wpf). This explains how you can create your own. This should be relatively easy to accomplish in Blend.